# ASP.NET MVC AdminPanel and Front Section File Structure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on this ASP.NET MVC Project to which i am very new.
I did some worked somehow on normal ASP.NET Web Forms back in days but i am really a beginner in ASP.NET. I developing projects in php for quite time and did never got a chance to try out .NET.

**Back To Question:**
I want to have two Sections, One for Administrators and One for Front End Users.
I want both Front End Users and Administrator(BackEnd) Users To have Different Themes Different Controller and Different Models.

In Simple PHP i did made base Controller Named `My_Controller` which extends the main Controller.
And after that i created two more base controllers derived from this my_controllers namely

- AdminController
- FrontEndController

and moved this based controllers to core directory or library directory.

But How to achieve such a thing in ASP.NET MVC, I am using **ASP.NET MVC 5** at the moment.

Currently i just created new project using MVC. and Here below is the Current File Structure for my Project

[image]

Also Please Also Share what will be a better approach that making the base controllers for Admin Controller and FrontEnd Controller.
Or having Multiple MVC Projects in a project of a solution. Like HMVC.

But most importantly what is the best approach and how to achieve this admin and frontend file Structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Possible Solution 1:**

The Good idea might be to use Area Feature of Asp.NET MVC. Area generally used for the purpose of sepration of user base, like in your case Public user and admin user.

Well explained details of area's can be found on following documentation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28VS.100%29.aspx

Regarding the different themes for Admin and user web app, you can simply use different Layouts. Put two layout inside the View > Shared  folder.  Then specify layout on each view as below.

For User Views

```
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_UserLayout.cshtml";
```

For Admin Views

```
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
```

**Possible Solution 2:**

if your project is big enough to think it will be difficult to handle the Areas later in a single project, you can also split the User and Admin project.

But you should be aware of re-usability of the source code by placing such code (such as Models) in other projects and adding reference.

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Many thanks, i did some search, MVC Areas seems a very good Approach.